# Regex for numbers only allowing spaces and 1 comma or dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to make a regex matching the following conditions :

- Only numbers
- Spaces allowed (breaking and non-breaking) but no more than one consecutive space
- Only one comma `,` OR only one dot `.`  allowed (not both)
- *Edit :* Starting and ending character should be a number or the sign `-` (maximum 1 `-`)

This should match  strings such as :
`4564654`, `4 454 845 484`, `874584.42`, `42 424 484.45`, `874584,42`, `42 424 484,45`...

And not match `42a`, `42.45,42`...

I tried to expand this one : `^[0-9[,.!?]*$` but I'm not succeeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a character class to match either a dot or a comma followed by 1+ digits in an optional group:

```
^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?: \d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)*$
```

That will match

- `^` Start of the string
- `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional part to match either a dot or a comma followed by 1+ digits
- `(?: \d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)*` repeat the previous part 0+ times with a space at the start
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GwxBxR/1)

**Update**

If the string can only contain a single dot or comma:

```
^(?!(?:[^.,\n]*[.,]){2})\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?:[^\S\n\r]\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)*$
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!(?:[^.,\n]*[.,]){2})` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not 2 times a dot or comma
- `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits, optionally match a dot or comma and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^\S\n\r]` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), not match a non-whitespace char and not match a newline
  - `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits, optionally match a dot or comma and 1+ digits
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UcwCVa/1)

```js
let regex = /^(?!(?:[^.,\n]*[.,]){2})\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?:[^\S\n\r]\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)*$/;
[
  "424242424",
  "424242.424",
  "454545.58",
  "4545454,4545",
  "45454,45",
  "4 45 44454.45",
  "4 454 454,45",
  "1 2 3",
  "1 2 3",
  "4,2 424 484,45 34.4 3 4",
  "545g45",
  "454.454.45",
  "45454,454,45",
  "45.44,45",
  "45,45.45",
  "4 4545 4545 45  45",
].forEach(s => console.log(s + ": " + regex.test(s)))
```

Comment: Good answer but is a little incorrect as it allows more than one comma/dot. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GwxBxR/2)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi That is in the question `This should match strings such as `

Comment: If you read the title of this post `Regex for numbers only allowing spaces and 1 comma or dot` it clearly says allow spaces but 1 comma or dot. Also, OP lists string as invalid which contains both dot and comma which is incorrectly `42.45,42` allowed in your regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GwxBxR/3) See your regex allows this `4,2 424 484,45 34.4 3 4` which clearly should not be allowed. It has multiple commas and dot as well. Also it is clearly written in his second bullet point `Only one comma , OR only one dot . allowed (not both)`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Check it again, `42.45,42` is not allowed https://regex101.com/r/GwxBxR/3. The title says `Regex for numbers only allowing spaces and 1 comma or dot` so per value apart from the space it matches 1 comma or 1 dot which is also in the example data of the question.

Comment: `42.45,42` is not allowed is okay but it should not allow strings as per the rule `Only one comma , OR only one dot . allowed (not both)` this `42.45,42` was listed as only one example. Following that OP's rule even `4,2 424 484,45 34.4 3 4` shouldn't be allowed. Hope you're getting my point.

Comment: Sorry if I was missleading, but indeed, only one comma or one dot should be allowed, regardless of the spaces. Therefore `4,2 424 484,45 34.4 3 4` should not match, upvoting anyway for the detailed explanations.

Comment: Yes, except for the `not more than one consecutive space` part, it seems good.

Comment: Yes it is ! Thanks. Could you update your exaplanations in your answer ? i.e. why is there line feeds `\n`  or `\t`

Comment: @Ellone I have updated it. The negated character class `[^\S\n\r]` Matches a whitespace character except a `\r` or `\n`. The `\t` what was in there was a typo, I have changed that.

Comment: I made a small change in order to accept negative numbers, so basically, it just also allows a `-` at the beginning of the string : `^(?!(?:[^.,\n]*[.,]){2})[-\d]+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?:[^\S\n\r]\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)*$` but how can I make it accept only one `-` ?

Comment: Not exactly, it should allow only one `-` maximum, and only at the beginning of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex,

```
^(?=^[\d ]+[,.]?[\d ]+$)\d+(?:[ .,]\d+)*$
```

Here, `(?=^[\d ]+[,.]?[\d ]+$)` positive look ahead ensures, that there is only one comma or dot present while `\d+(?:[ .,]\d+)*` takes care of the format and allowed characters.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1B6Hgr/1)**

Comment: I think it only misses breaking spaces, this one works with simple spaces, but not breaking spaces, for tests, the shortcut for a breaking space is `Alt+0160`. But I can't figure out where to add it.

Comment: I thought it should be : `^(?=^[\d\s]+[,.]?[\d]+$)\d+(?:[ .,]\d+)*$`. But it looks like \s doesn't match the Alt+0160 breaking-space character.

Comment: It seems that this breaking space is not handled by the regex, neither with `\s` nor `\u0160` : 
In this example, https://regex101.com/r/1B6Hgr/3 the last line that should match contains the breaking space between the `2`and the `3`

Comment: @Ellone: Changed the regex to use `\s` and it works fine. [Check it out](https://regex101.com/r/1B6Hgr/5). Also another version I made also works by changing the regex a bit to effectively use `\s` without `\n` [Check this as well](https://regex101.com/r/1B6Hgr/4)

Comment: @Ellone: Also, I read about your requirement for having an optional negative sign before the number, for which you just had to include `-?` in the regex. [You can check here](https://regex101.com/r/1B6Hgr/6)

Answer (score 0):

Some digits or spaces first:

```
^[0-9 ]*
```

then, a comma or a point:

```
(\.|,)?
```

Then, some more digits and/or spaces, and the end of the expression:

```
[0-9 ]*$
```

Together:

```
^[0-9 ]*(.|,)?[0-9 ]*$
```

Comment: That matches `42a` or an empty string.

Comment: Right. `.` is a special character. Correcting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `^(\d*? ?\d)+(,|\.)?\d+$`

test cases https://regex101.com/r/DDdvf3/4